# My DSL connection drops pings and my VPN to work times out. How do I determine where the issue is?

Tags: ping, dsl

I've been working from home for about 3 months now.  At first my vpn to work was fine.  But the longer I worked from home, the more often my VPN would crash.  I started running a constant ping to 8.8.8.8.  When the ping stops replying my VPN goes down.  I'm trying to figure out how to determine where the issue is.  Is it in my network? In the DSL circuit? In CenturyLink's network? or the Internet?  and how to prove it.

My internet provider is centurylink.

Answer (score 1):

Linux, plausibly also available for Windows:

`mtr` as in "my traceroute" is a great tool for this kind of questions.

Find, install and then run mtr as in `mtr -i 5  8.8.8.8` and you will be presented with a display of the intermediate nodes (IP's) that your packets are sent through.

hit d to cycle the display through different formats, or h for terse "help".

mtr has a number of options for e.g. reporting.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows

Windows equivalent (as if anything is equivalent lol)

Comment: pathping is better than tracert on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your network traffic to work is inside a tunnel.

First, in your VPN App, turn Logging ON. You need the log at the point the VPN stops.  I assume you mean the VPN stops; not the PC crashing.

Second, with the log, determine if traffic is stopping at your place (that is, not getting out), or past your place at your employer's location.

Third, check with work and supply your log. They may be able to see the VPN stop at their end.

Fourth:  You probably should reinstall the VPN app. Uninstall, restart the computer, install the VPN app and set it up. This also may fix your issue because the VPN app integrates directly into your network settings inside the computer. If it screws up, it can affect your network connection (and the ping issue you saw).

Finally, and only if no other solution, as your ISP. See if the Ping issue rests with the ISP.